# Creating a function to cross reference df values to a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am working on a project to allow me to cross reference that values of a df to the standard values found in multiple different dictionaries.

here is my minimal sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
 
data= [["English",np.nan,"smith","Alabama","","","","manufacturing","Access","Commercial","","",""]]

df= pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Communication_Language__c','firstName', 'lastName', 'state', 'country', 'company', 'email', 'industry', 'System_Type__c', 'AccountType', 'customerSegment', 'Existing_Customer__c', 'GDPR_Email_Permission__c'])

error_dict={}
```

Here are the dictionaries I want to cross reference:

```
lang_dict= {"English":"ENG", "French":"FR"}
states_dict= {"Alabama": "AL", "Alaska": "AK"}
```

I have created a couple functions to cross reference the data based on the keys found in the parsing dictionary

```
def lang(df_lang, column="lang", lang_dict=lang_dict):
    for k, v in lang_dict.items():
       df_lang[column] = df[column].replace(k,v)
    return df_lang

def states(df_states, column="state", states_dict=states_dict):
    for i,j in states_dict.items():
        df_states[column]=df[column].replace(i,j)
    return df_states

parsing_map={
"state":[states],
"Communication_Language__c": [lang]
}
```

I want combine these functions into a single function since they are doing the same thing just cross referencing different dictionaries. I hvae been provided with some pseudocode to assist me but I still do not understand how this is working

```
def cross_reference(dataframe, error_dict, column_name, reference_dict_path = None):
    if reference_dict_path == None:
       reference_dict = Load_Json(column_name + '.json')
    else:
        reference_dict = Load_Json(reference_dict_path)
        relevent_column = dataframe[column_name]

#  SOME OPERATION ON dataframe AND error_dict
    return dataframe, error_dict

parsing_map={
"state":[states],
"Communication_Language__c": [lang]
}

for i in parsing_map.keys():
   df, error_dict = parsing_map[i](df, error_dict, i)
```

The values found in the dataframe maybe or may not match the items found in the reference dictionaries (lang_dict and State_dict). I want to use that pseudocode provided to call the df columns through the function by referencing the keys found in the parsing_map dictionary.

Can someone help me understand what this pseudocode is saying and how I can apply this pseudocode to combine the two current functions I have currently?

Comment: The pandas `.replace` function gets passed a dictionary.  For every item in the column, if the item is a key in the dictionary, then it returns the associated value.  I think that's exactly what you're looking for, right?

Comment: `.replace` helps with the operations in the function but im confused on how to reference both `lang_dict` and `states_dict` without calling the column name directly from the df but instead i want to use the `parsing_map` keys to assign the function

Comment: This was easier to do when using two functions to reference `state_dict` and `lang_dict` separately but since they are both doing the same operation I was wondering if there is a way to combine those two functions together using a function similar to the pseudocode

Comment: The key point is that your `lang` and `states` functions do not have to use loops.  The pandas `replace` function accepts a dictionary, and can convert the entire column or dataframe with one call.  Your parsing thing is solving a problem you don't really have.